# How to images show in Wp8 i have a stream Path

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a one zip url and i have done to zip file to unzip file . in unzip file are 4 to 5 images are jpg . how to these images show in page ..

```
private void openReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    UnZipper unzip = new UnZipper(e.Result);
    foreach (string filename in unzip.GetFileNamesInZip())
    {
        Stream stream = unzip.GetFileStream(filename);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(contents);
    }
}
```

Please Help ..............................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, consume imgCtr is your Image Control is page.

```
private void openReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    UnZipper unzip = new UnZipper(e.Result);
    foreach (string filename in unzip.GetFileNamesInZip())
    {
        Stream stream = unzip.GetFileStream(filename);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(stream);
        imgCtr.Source = image;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou this is working . one more this is foreach Loop and there are 4 to 5 images how to i add dynamically show this images one by one

Comment: you can add the bitmapImages into a list. then display one by one using timer or storyboard.

Comment: You are welcome. vote the question and answer to let it saw by more people.